# How to wait particular up to particular time limit until get response from rest service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, httpclient

In my code i am calling one external web service to get response by using HTTP Client Get request. Here the service may delay up to 5 mins to give the response. So i have to do below things.
1. want to set request timeout(No idea how to do it)
2. call the service and set the time limit up to what time it can wait for response(In my case i want to set time limit for 5 mins)

can any one suggest me how can i achieve this 2 things.

Thanks,

Sudheer

Comment: I am able to find how to set request time out i am using  PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager ConnManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(timeToLive,TimeUnit.MINUTES); . Stil no clue how to wait until get the response.

Answer (score 1):

You can set timeout for request using:

```
RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setConnectTimeout(30 * 1000).build();
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().setDefaultRequestConfig(requestConfig).build();
```

For setting timeout for response,you can wrap the call in thread and set the timeout for that thread.

PFB the code snippet below:

```
Future<T> future = null;
future = pool.submit(new Callable<T>() {
    public T call() {
        return executeImpl(url);
    }   
}); 

try {
    return future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}   
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    log.warn("task interrupted", name);
}   
catch (ExecutionException e) {
    log.error(name + " execution exception", e); 
}   
catch (TimeoutException e) {
    log.debug("future timed out", name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you kaur for your response. Above you used Future call to wait for response. I am confused as you mentioned to wrap the call in thread.